# Transparent bitmap 32bit as window background

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I set a graphic in bmp 32bit format as window background with TRANSPARENCY? when i use bmp 28bit everything works but then there is no transparency. When i use 32bit bitmap with alpha the background is not rendered.

Application is in c ++ winapi.

```
bool ApplicationInit(HINSTANCE hinstance)
{

    //HBITMAP hbmp = LoadBitmap(hinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_LAUNCHER_BG));
    HBITMAP hbmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    HBRUSH hbr = CreatePatternBrush(hbmp);

    WNDCLASSEX wcx;

    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);
    wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = LauncherWndProc;
    wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcx.hInstance = hinstance;
    wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(hinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON));
    wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcx.hbrBackground = hbr;
    wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcx.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcx);
}
```

please help :)

Comment: What sort of transparency are you looking for? Key-color transparency? Alpha transparency? Should the image be transparent with respect to the window background? Should the window background be transparent with respect to what's underneath it?

Comment: @IInspectable the window background should be transparent with respect to what's underneath it. I want the main window of the application to be an image in png / bmp format that has irregular shapes, so I want to render the transparency behind it.

Comment: Assuming that you want either fully transparent or fully opaque (with no translucency) the easiest would be to use [SetWindowRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn). Otherwise, you're going to have to create a [layered window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows).

Comment: @IInspectable a layered window would be easier than using a region. Simply remove any alpha from the bitmap and fill in the desired transparent areas with a given color, draw the bitmap onto the window, and use SetLayeredWindowAttributes() to set the transparent color, done. The OS takes care of the rest. With a region, you have to parse the bitmap and convert the transparent areas into runs of rectangles, and then build up the region using ExtCreateRegion() then SetWindowRgn(), so it is more work. Layered windows were invented to replace irregularly shaped regions